# Java: Counting instances in an object

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the code:

```
int number;
for (Vartype var : dataset) {
    number++;
}
```

This code does work, but `var` is never used. How else can this code be written so Java isn't complaining about an unused variable? "dataset" is an object.

Comment: _This code does work_ but this code doesn't even compile :)

Comment: what datatype is dataset?

Comment: If `dataset` is `Collection` then maybe use `size()` method. If array then you have `length` field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java's not complaining about the unused variable, your IDE is.

Instead of looping over each object in that array/`Collection`, you can just use its size to see how many elements are there.

```
// if dataset is an array:
int number = dataset.length;

// if dataset is a Collection:
int number = dataset.size();
```

Comment: @vels4j there is minimal time that need to pass before any answer can be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

The for-each as per your post will count the number of members in 'dataset' if it is a collection object.
You can also use   for-loop for this.
or simply check the size of the object if it is a collection object.

Comment: Why?  If it's a collection, you already have O(1) access to its size through a method call.